# Is it good idea to use LocomotiveCMS only to get multi-site feature?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to make multi-site multi-domain website using Rails.

Because I don't have experience with Rails or Ruby, I'm looking for something that already have multi-site features, and I prefer easier approach.

The only thing I need in LocomotiveCMS is the multi-site feature.

Do you think it is a good idea to choose LocomotiveCMS in my case?

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider django-cms a more mature solution.
Or learn rails. The documentation (multisite) kinda falls short at the moment.